# How to update a program downloaded from Github using Pip or Git?

Tags: git, github, pip

I have recently downloaded a program file from Github using the following commands >>>

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/SomeUser/SomeProgram.git
 $ cd SomeProgram
 $ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Now a new version of the program has come, how to update to the latest version of the program?

Should I have to use Pip or Git? I would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: you may first fork that repo then clone it then you can update your local repo. Have a look at this tuto : https://www.neonscience.org/resources/learning-hub/tutorials/git-setup-remote

Comment: @cizario there is no need to fork the repo first

Comment: @ImArghya7 How did you actually install the module `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` only installed the dependencies of the module that you have downloaded

Comment: @FlyingTeller I followed the exact method that was mentioned in the Readme section of the Github Repo.

Comment: Can you add the link to the github to your question? It is difficult to help you when it is unclear what steps you took for the installation and what kind of program we are talking about here

Comment: @FlyingTeller Sure, here it is >>> https://github.com/Dineshkarthik/telegram_media_downloader

Answer (score 0):

First, update the source code to the latest version:

```
cd SomeProgram
git pull
```

Then, install the latest dependencies:

```
pip3 install -r requirements
```

Now you should be able to use the updated version